# Why are my environment variables not being seen - rspec 3.1.0, rails engine 4.1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, environment-variables

I have the following test file, in the `before(:each)do ... end` section I am using some enviroment variables, these - because I have no idea if spec reads from dummy or the engine `config/` its self, are placed in both the dummy's `config/application.yml` and the engines root `config/application.yml`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Xaaron::UsersController, :type => :controller do
  routes { Xaaron::Engine.routes }

  context "publish created users" do
    before(:each) do
      Xaaron.configuration.reset
      no_user_member_roles_relation

      binding.pry
      Xaaron.configuration.publish_to_black_bird = true
      Xaaron.configuration.black_bird_api_url = ENV['BLACKBIRD_API_URL']
      Xaaron.configuration.black_bird_api_key = ENV['BLACKBIRD_API_KEY']

    end

    it "should publish to blackbird" do
      VCR.use_cassette 'publisher/create_user_response' do
        post :create, user: {
          first_name: 'sample', user_name: 'johnq',
          email: 'sample_sample_sample@sample.com', email_confirmation: 'sample_sample_sample@sample.com',
          password: 'SamplePassword', password_confirmation: 'SamplePassword'
        }

        expect(response).to redirect_to login_path
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Now because this is local host testing, I don't care if I show you these (both apps are on localhost):

The `application.yml` file in both locations contain the following:

```
BLACKBIRD_API_KEY: d1cab0ac344f5074797b8c2b9ce90070e8af3405de8431fa17150a0f3420b41e
BLACKBIRD_API_URL: http://site.local.com::5000/api/internal/v1/
```

When the test is run it fails, because of a nil:NilClass, which happens in this method:

```
# We need to check if Blackbird is alive.
def is_alive?
  # Do a simple get and capture the response
  response = HTTParty.get(
    Xaaron.configuration.black_bird_api_url + 'alive/',
    :headers => { "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" => Xaaron.configuration.black_bird_api_key }
  )

  # If the response is 200 return true, else reeturn thje response code
  if response.code == 200
    return true
  else
    return response.code
  end
end
```

The exact line is:

```
Xaaron.configuration.black_bird_api_url + 'alive/'
```

When I place a `binding.pry` above this line and do `Xaaron.configuration.black_bird_api_url` I get `nil`, so when I do `ENV['BLACKBIRD_API_URL']` I also get `nil`

So My question is:

**Why are my environment variables nil when they are oh so very clearly set.**

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't load environment variables by default unless you specify them from the command line when you invoke Rails. You want to use [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) or [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) to be able to load environment variables from a file. I believe you want figaro, since it reads from `application.yml` rather than a `.env` file.

Comment: I figured some one was going to state this, and I should have stated I am already using Figaro. Its how I am able to have an `application.yml` and use `ENV['SOME_KEY_HERE']`, The problem is even in testing doing `Figaro.env.BLACKBIRD_API_URL` comes back `nil`, when clearly - it is not `nil`. @dankohn

Comment: But then your bug seems to be in your use of Figaro, not in the code you include. I would try to get Figaro working, or switch to dotenv (which is what I use).

Comment: Thats not a very helpful answer. Based on what I provided I cannot see any bugs being introduced. and I cannot see how switching would help.